# Get url of a queue from javax.jms.Queue instance

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, tibco, tibco-ems

In my Java application I am connecting to a Tibco queue. The url of the Tibco queue is `net.tems://server000002.test01.india.intranet:30002/queue/TEST_DOMAIN.001.TEST_QUEUE.001`

In my java app, I have an instance of `javax.jms.Queue` which corresponds to this queue.
If I use a method `javax.jms.Queue.getQueueName()`, I get this part: `TEST_DOMAIN.001.TEST_QUEUE.001`.
I would like to know how can I get this part: `net.tems://server000002.test01.india.intranet:30002/queue/` from the `javax.jms.Queue` instance.

Perhaps it is very easy, but I looked at the javadoc for `javax.jms.Queue` and I couldn't find anything that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get proprietary information about a Tibco queue using the standard JMS API, and that won't work.

Tibco likely offers an extension of the JMS API for developers to perform Tibco-specific messaging features, and getting this information is probably one of them.

Browse the Tibco API documentation, specifically, the JMS extension API, you should find your answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some samples of how to use the TIBCO JAVA API in this path (in case of windows):

**C:\tibco\ems[version]\samples\java**

Hope this helps,